# Excel VBA Array from Range Starting at -1 rather than 0

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with VBA in Excel.  I want the user to be able to choose a vertical set of contiguous cells and put the values of those cells into an array.  The below code does this but I can't figure out why Debug.Print DatArr(0) prints the value of one cell above the selected area.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Sub reconcile()
Dim DatArr As Range
Dim AuxDat As Range
Dim StartCellRange As String
Dim CellCnt As Integer


    Set DatArr = Application.InputBox("Select a contiguous range of cells.", "SelectARAnge Demo",   Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
    CellCnt = DatArr.Count


    DatArr.Select

    Selection.Offset(0, -1).Select


    Set AuxDat = Selection
    Debug.Print AuxDat.Count
    Debug.Print AuxDat(0)
    Debug.Print DatArr(0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the **Option Base** statement affects *arrays* rather than *ranges.*
So you are looking one cell **before** the start of the range.

Comment: As a point of clarity, the `Option Base` setting used would have no impact on the output in the OP's code.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner .........You are absolutely correct!!.......... **Option Base** could have been omitted completely since no array is being generated by the posted code.

Comment: Not just that, Option Base only affects declared arrays where the lower bound is not specified.  A Range.Value array will be base 1 always, regardless of Option Base.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference `AuxDat` and `DatArr` *with respect to the range* they respresent:

```
' First cell in AuxDat.
Debug.Print AuxDat.Cells(1, 1).Value

' First cell in DatArr.
Debug.Print DatArr.Cells(1, 1).Value
```

Accessing via, for example `AuxDat(x)`, will allow any any value even though it is outside your selected range (as long as it fits within Excel's bounds). For example (using your code), select range `$B$5:$B$7`:

```
Debug.Print AuxDat(-1) ' This is allowed and will print A3.
Debug.Print AuxDat(5) ' This is allowed and will print A9.
```

Answer (score 0):

Editing your code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub reconcile()
Dim DatArr As Range
Dim AuxDat As Range
Dim CellCnt As Integer

Set DatArr = _
    Application.InputBox( _
      "Select a contiguous range of cells.", _
      "SelectARAnge Demo", _
      Selection.Address, , , , , 8)

CellCnt = DatArr.Count

If DatArr.Columns(1).Column > 1 Then  '<<small error trap in case the user selects column A
    Set AuxDat = DatArr.Offset.Offset(0, -1)
End If

Debug.Print AuxDat.Count
Debug.Print AuxDat(1).Value
Debug.Print DatArr(1).Value
End Sub
```

As Gary's Student has stated Ranges are collections of cells which are indexed from 1.